# Programmatically determine whether the connection is taking place over HTTP or over HTTPS?

Tags: php, https

I'd like to redirect users of my site from `http://mysite` to `https://mysite`.

How can I do that programmatically in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is set to `on`, the page is loaded over https. However, you should mark your cookies as secure, which you can do with one of the parameters of `setcookie`. If the cookies are not secure, they may be transmitted over unencrypted http, and can potentially be stolen, even if the user is redirected immediately.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

For the actual redirect, I'd use a .htaccess rewrite, rather than PHP. Create a .htaccess file with the following content.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The only cookie I use is the session cookie. Should I mark it as secure as well?

Comment: Where do I have to save the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: In the web root (top level) directory. Also make sure the file starts with the period.

Comment: And yes, you should mark it as secure too. You can do this by executing php_ini('session.cookie_secure',true) before using any session_* functions.

Comment: Can that `php_ini` call be replaced with an actual setting in my `php.ini` file?

Comment: Yes, of course. But not having access to the php.ini file is the rule, not the exception nowadays, so I gave you the safe bet.

Comment: `php_ini` is neither a php function not an htaccess directive. Use `ini_set()` in ÜHÜ pr `php_value` in .htaccess

Answer (score 7):

You can check if SSL is used using `if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))`.

If you are using the standard port, testing for `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443` will also work, but of course checking if HTTPS is used is better than testing if the port is the default SSL port.

---

However, the redirect should not be done via PHP but via .htaccess (if you are using Apache):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to determine.

Answer (score 2):

If it's https, then the variable `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` will be set to nonzero:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    # it's https
} else {
    # it's not https
}
```

Comment: That will raise an `E_NOTICE` as `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` does not exist when SSL is not used. Use `isset()` or `!empty()`